# Create a command that can only be used once in a specific timespan (JDA)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to code a `>deadchat` command that can only be used once an hour, so people don't misuse it. I tried a few things like simple timers but nothing seems to work. Is there a specific method for that? (It's a simple text command in a MessageReceivedEvent if that matters)

*btw: Please don't immediately close my post for too few details. It's just a simple question. If you need to know something more, ask. Also don't harass me for not knowing this. I'm still learning. I did search on Google and this platform and I did try some things but nothing worked.*

Comment: You can try adding more details about *did try some things but nothing worked.*

Comment: show the code you've written where you made an attempt to solve this problem

Comment: I tried to start a timer that should start after the command was executed so it should stop the bot from getting another command. But that was probably nonsense and just threw a lot of errors. I basically just want a cooldown that says "Wait another 20 minutes until you can use this command again" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a timestamp of when the command was last used and then only allow using it if the time passed since that timestamp is over an hour.

Here is an example:

```java
private final Map<Long, Long> timestamps = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if (!event.getContentRaw().equals(">deadchat")) return;
    long channelId = event.getChannel().getIdLong();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long lastUsed = timestamps.get(channelId);
    // Check how long ago the timestamp was
    if (lastUsed != null && now - lastUsed < TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1)) {
        return; // cooldown of 1 hour
    }
    // Update timestamp to now, next use only permitted in an hour
    timestamps.put(channelId, now);
    
    .... code that runs command ....
}
```